# Issue related to Calling webservice using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have following code :

```
  <script src="Content/Script/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function GetData() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://64.93.78.32/LocalPlatFormService.svc/GetJobRCompanies",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: ajaxCallSucceed,
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            }

            function ajaxCallSucceed(response) {
                alert(response);
                var finalStr = '';
                var a = response[0].Success;
                if (a.toString().toLowerCase() == "true") {

                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        var strId = response[i].Id;
                        var strSuccess = response[i].Success;
                        finalStr += i + '.' + strId + ' , ' + strSuccess + ' ';
                    }

                    alert(finalStr);
                }
                else {
                    alert("No Data Found.");
                }
            }
    </script>
```

The above code works fine when i use `url: "/LocalPlatFormService.svc/GetJobRCompanies"`
that is local webservice in my project solution.
but it doesn't work with

`url: "http://64.93.78.32/LocalPlatFormService.svc/GetJobRCompanies"`

What is wrong in my Code??

if you use `http://64.93.78.32/LocalPlatFormService.svc` link in your browser it gives perfact json string..  then whats wrong with live URL ?

Thanks.

Comment: Set up an error callback and see what the issue is.

Comment: Ensure you enabled CORS

Answer (score 0):

i think it's cross-domain policy you are facing. Try using [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) instead of `JSON`